# How do I measure JSON properties reading performance?

Tags: json, performance, react-native

I have a static dataset inside a react-native app. There are 3 JSON files: 500kb, 2mb and 10mb.
Each of them contains a JSON object with ~8000 keys.

I'm concerned if this will cause any performance issues. Atm I'm using redux toolkit state mainly for ids and reading data through selectors inside the redux connect method. In some cases, I have to access those JSON files sequentially ~100 times in a row, pulling certain properties by key (no array find or something).

Tbh, I still don't know it if 10mb is a significant amount at all?

How do I measure performance and where do I read more about using large JSON files in react-native apps?

Comment: Did you consider storing such data in [sqlite](https://sqlite.org/) databases? 10 megabytes will take at least one second to be transmitted by most networks

Comment: this data is stored in the app bundle, so network doesn't matter. Also, it can be gzipped into ~500kb. Why use sqlite? I don't need any of it's querying capabilities